# MPI.Init problems in Java applet.

Tags: java, applet, mpi

I've just started learning about MPI's and I'm trying to implement it in a java game of life applet but I am having trouble with the MPI.Init() argument. I'm unsure what String[] to use when there is no main method to grab the String[] args from.

My knowledge in this area is very minimal so any help is greatly appreciated,
Cheers.

Comment: ..you are actually using *"..Message Passing Interface, a library for distributed memory parallel programming and the de facto standard method for using distributed memory clusters for high-performance technical computing."* in this applet?  What for?  *"I'm unsure what String[] to use when there is no main method to grab the String[] args from."*  applets have an `init()` method.  Combine that with [`getParameter(name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getParameter-java.lang.String-) to make an array of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would like to use Message Passing Interface for an applet, but `MPI.Init()` can be called with an empty `String[]` (not `null`). After all the `MPI.Init()` doesn't do that much with the arguments (this can be deduced from [here](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Init.3.php)).

I must admit though that I really doubt whether you really want to be making applets using MPI.